# Sitecore SxA Sites - Best Practices

Tags: sxa, best-practices

Are there any Sitecore demos or other sites built using Sitecore SxA, keeping best practices in mind? Any information would be help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two projects that I am aware of:

- [XA.Reference](https://github.com/alan-null/XA.Reference/releases) - it contains basic site with basic configuration for all the renderings. Next release will include demo blog site as well
- [Sitecore.XA.Showcase](https://github.com/Cognifide/Sitecore.XA.Showcase/releases) - more advanced site. It describes SXA features and renderings using SXA site.

source: [SXA.Index](https://github.com/alan-null/SXA.Index#demo-sites)